# DBT snapshot command recreates table every time, does not add the dbt fields

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, snapshot, dbt

I am working at my first snapshot prototype with dbt and BigQuery. It has the following configuration:

```
{{
        config(
          target_schema=REDACTED,
          strategy='check',
          unique_key=REDACTED,
          check_cols='all',
          materialized='table',
          cluster_by = REDACTED,
          labels = REDACTED
        )
    }}
```

In the beginning it worked fine, on the first `dbt snapshot` the table was created and it had the field `dbt_valid_from` and `dbt_valid_to`.

The first run showed:

`[CREATE TABLE (228.0 rows, 21.4 KB processed) in 4.71s]`

On the second run it showed:

`[MERGE (0.0 rows, 37.7 KB processed) in 11.24s]`

Then for some reason, this stopped working. Now every time I run `dbt snapshot`, the table is recreated from scratch. What's more, it doesn't have the dbt fields `dbt_valid_from` and `dbt_valid_to`. So it's understandable that dbt cannot make the snapshotting work.

I tried reversing all of my actions, but I can't get out of this problem. I also tried deleting the `target` folder with the compiled files. How can I get snapshotting to work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was with adding `materialized='table'` in the snapshot configuration. I thought that without this, the snapshot would be a view. But that’s not the case. So I will omit this option altogether.